# select previous and next elements on hover

Tags: css, attributes, hover

I have some html which looks something like this

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply a style on any specific `<li>` on hover AND apply a different style to the previous and next `<li>` elements (the one next to the hovered one).

If possible I want to do this with pure css (no JS).

So to be clear there are 3 different states and 3 different sets of styles a `<li>` could have

- the element is hovered over.
- the element is not hovered over but the element before or after it is hovered over.
- the element is not hovered over and the elements before or after it are not hovered over.

I know that the :hover psudo selector can be used to apply a style to the hovered element - no problem

I know that the next element can be selected with :hover + li - no problem

Applying a style to the previous element is however a problem.

I know there is no previous sibling selector, is this still the case?

I have looked at another stack overflow post which talks about applying a style directly to the previous sibling and then using two adjasent sibling selectors to apply styles to the 2nd and 3rd elements. I cant do that in this case because the hover has to be on the 2nd element.

I have considered using [attribute] selectors combined with attr() 
my plan would be to give each li a data attribute and a unique specific number, ie `<li data="1">` 
on hover the attr() feature would be used to read the previous elements data attribute and then pass that to the [attribute] selector.

it might look something like this

```css
li:hover [data-number-type=attr(data-number-type)]
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-number-type="1">Owl</li>
  <li data-number-type="2">Owl</li>
  <li data-number-type="3">Owl</li>
  <li data-number-type="4">Owl</li>
<ui/>
```

That snippet of code does not work.
but is there any way to get something like that working?

Is there any other css only way that i have not considered?

Comment: li:hover ~ li {
      //do something
    }

Comment: @ShafikulIslam The general sibling combinator `~` selector "matches the second element only if it follows the first element (though not necessarily immediately)". Therefore it cannot select previous elements.

Comment: a *previous* or *parent* element selector can be inefficient if CSS implements it and that's *exactly* why it is not... JS is there for such reasons :)

Comment: Essentially... **NO**.

Comment: https://codepen.io/DevCubeHD/pen/ejopmv same problem for me... anyways selector does not work as exspected